# AZCopy development to production

Tags: azure, azcopy, azure-storage-emulator

I can copy from production to development just fine, but when I try to copy from development to production I get this error:

> 404, resource not found.

For the command:

> AzCopy /Dest:https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/appimage /Source:http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/appimage /DestKey:key /SourceType:blob /SourceKey:Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw== /S

I have tried both storage emulator 5.0 and the latest 5.3 and different AZ copies. All my containers are public access.

This error just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported to transfer from storage emulator to cloud directly. [See this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/7580).

You can add `/SyncCopy` parameter to your command. 
It automatically downloads blobs  from emulator  to local memory and then uploads them to cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasted hours on this. This needs to be documented somewhere on their docs...